# OpenGL ES 2.0 render to texture with transparent background

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, render-to-texture

I would like to create an interactive 2D effect that I can put on anything. So I want to take a mostly transparent effect, render it to a texture, and put it wherever I want simply by putting it on a square.

The problem I encountered is that I can't get rid of the background color. When I put the effect over an object, the background color of the effect blocks out the object that I want to put the effect over.

Here is my code. Can anybody tell me what I'm missing?

Drawing:

```
GLES20.glClearColor(0.6f, 0.34f, 0.14f, 0.0f);
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

ball.draw();  //This is the object a simple square draw with 2 triangles
particleSystem.renderToTexture(); //effect rendering to texture and drawing it
```

The render to texture code code:

```
public void renderToTexture(){
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb[0]);
    GLES20.glClear( GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex[0], 0);
    GLES20.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRb[0]);
    int status = GLES20.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);

    drawRender();  //draws the effect on a fbo and saving the texture to renderTex[0]

    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex[0]);
    drawEffect(); //draws a square with the effect texture on it
```

The problem should be here somewhere, but I have no idea what to do. I tried everything I could think of. I even triend to dispose of the background color in the shader.

Comment: This looks fine, so the problem is most likely elsewhere in the code. What format is the texture you use as framebuffer attachment (`renderTex[0]`)? Make sure that you use a format with an alpha component. Other possible problems could be the clear color used for `renderToTexture()`, or the fragment shader used for `Drawing()`.

Comment: @RetoKoradi thaaank youu. I'm so dub I used this:  GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, texW, texH, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, null); 
Ofc it didn't show any transparency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code looks perfectly fine. You will need to make sure that the texture you use for the color render target (`renderTex[0]`) has an alpha component.

Note that the number of texture formats in ES 2.0 that are guaranteed to be color-renderable is very limited. The only two with an alpha component (see table 4.5. in the spec) are `GL_RGBA4` and `GL_RGB5_A1`. Most notably, this does **not** include `GL_RGBA` with 8 bits per component.

So for defining a color-renderable texture with alpha component that is *guaranteed* to work across all ES 2.0 implementations, you will have to use `GL_RGBA` for the internal format, and `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4` or `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_5_5_1` for the type argument of `glTexImage2D()`.

Most common devices (at least all the ones I have seen) do support the [OES_rgb8_rgba8](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_rgb8_rgba8.txt) extension, which adds support for rendering to 8 bit component textures. But if you want to be completely portable, you should check for the presence of this extension before using render targets with those formats.

Comment: I'm sad, with GL_RGBA my effect not even close looks as pretty as it was with RGB and with GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5 and the other two give back a black screen

Comment: How would you check for the presence of OES_rgb8_rgba8?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but i also encountered it right now and the solution for me was to do something with the GLSurfaceView. Just add these lines after setting the context

```
glSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0);
glSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

I was already using GL_RGBA format and was really annoyed that nothing else was working, but this worked like magic.